p-values for all pairs between two matrices to achieve matlab's corr function
I have been trying to implement in Python (with numpy and scipy) this variant of Matlab's corr function, but it seems I cannot solve it by myself. What I need is to implement the alternative Matlab corr implementation:
[rho,pval] = corr(X,Y)
I would appreciate any help on this!!!
What I tried:
I tried to modify the solutions posted here and in this other thread, without much success. For instance, I was able to hstack the two matrixes X and Y, and by keeping a part of the correlation matrix, I got the right result for the correlations. However, the same trick is NOT working for the p-values. Actually, both the solutions in the other threads gave me the (more or less) correct values for the correlation coefficients, which is great, but I cannot reproduce the behavior of the Matlab implementation for the p-values.
Also, the solution here aims to reproduce corrcoef's behaviour, which, according to Matlab's documentation, converts the input matrices into column vectors before computing the correlations.
On the other hand, I also tried to hstack the matrices in Matlab, and again got the same answer for the correlations, but the values are quite different for the p-values between what I get in Python and what I got in Matlab. This made me think that the problem perhaps is in the statistic being calculated. However, according to the Matlab documentation, it uses:

corr computes the p-values for Pearson's correlation using a Student's t distribution for a transformation of the correlation

and, from the documentation in SciPy I think they are using the same test, but I am not 100% sure, given that the bibligraphic reference there is for Student's paper, which is the one that Matlab's docs say it uses (Student's r), but as I said, I am NOT sure at all.

please if so kind, once this question solved, it would be nice for readers to know which one is faster, the MATLAB function corr or the Python version answering this question, thanks in advance

I think the easiest way is to do it in pandas, using scipy.stats pearsonr, which returns the pairwise rho and pval. I tested with some sample below, and I believe the results match the matlab results.
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
import pandas as pd


X = np.array([
    [0.5377, 0.3188, 3.5784, 0.7254],
    [1.8339, -1.3077, 2.7694, -0.0631],
    [-2.2588, -0.4336, -1.3499, 0.7147],
    [0.8622, 0.3426, 3.0349, -0.2050]
])

Y1 = np.array([
    [-0.1241, 0.6715, 0.4889, 0.2939],
    [1.4897, -1.2075, 1.0347, -0.7873],
    [1.4090, 0.7172, 0.7269, 0.8884],
    [1.4172, 1.6302, -0.3034, -1.1471]
])

Y2 = Y1
Y2[:, 3] = Y2[:, 3] + X[:, 1]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(X)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(Y2)

coeffmat = np.zeros((df1.shape[1], df2.shape[1]))
pvalmat = np.zeros((df1.shape[1], df2.shape[1]))

for i in range(df1.shape[1]):
    for j in range(df2.shape[1]):
        corrtest = pearsonr(df1[df1.columns[i]], df2[df2.columns[j]])

        coeffmat[i,j] = corrtest[0]
        pvalmat[i,j] = corrtest[1]

dfcoeff = pd.DataFrame(coeffmat, columns=df2.columns, index=df1.columns)
print(dfcoeff)
dfpvals = pd.DataFrame(pvalmat, columns=df2.columns, index=df1.columns)
print(dfpvals)

I also tried playing around with pandas corrwith function (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html#pandas.DataFrame.corrwith) but didn't spend enough time. I think there is a more elegant solution which uses that.
Hope this helps

thanks! That's perfect!
Note: it is a bit (very) slow, I will try to make it faster...

yes, i cant help but feel that there is a better way to do this but didn't have sufficient time to explore. Please let me know if you find a faster way.
